# Spell Scroller doesn't work

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm making a MagicBows plugin where you can select spells by doing left click and if you shoot the bow the selected spell will give its effect, but the selector doesn't work. I'm not sure how to fix this.

This is my Main file:

```
package me.Pixel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Effect;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.Arrow;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityShootBowEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
    public Main plugin;
    public List<String> spells = new ArrayList<String>();
    public getTargets getTargets = new getTargets();
    private Arrow arrow;
    public LightningShot LightningShot = new LightningShot(arrow);
    public ExplosionShot ExplosionShot = new ExplosionShot(arrow);

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {    
        plugin = this;
        this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
        getCommand("bow").setExecutor(new BowCommand());
        spells.add("LightningShot");
        spells.add("ExplosionShot");
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onEntityShootBow(EntityShootBowEvent event) {
        if(event.getProjectile() instanceof Arrow) {
            Arrow arrow = (Arrow) event.getProjectile();
            new LightningShot(arrow).runTaskTimer(this, 0, 1);
        }
    }       

    @EventHandler
    public void onEntityShootBow1(EntityShootBowEvent event) {
        if(event.getProjectile() instanceof Arrow) {
            Arrow arrow = (Arrow) event.getProjectile();
            new ExplosionShot(arrow).runTaskTimer(this, 0, 1);
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onClick(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
        if(e.getAction() == Action.LEFT_CLICK_AIR || e.getAction() == Action.LEFT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
            Player p = e.getPlayer();
            ItemStack stack = p.getItemInHand();
            if(stack != null && stack.getType() == Material.BOW && stack.hasItemMeta() && stack.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(ChatColor.RED + "Bow")) {
                int SpellSelected = stack.getDurability();
                if (SpellSelected < 2) {
                    stack.setDurability((short) (SpellSelected + 1));
                    p.getWorld().playEffect(p.getLocation(), Effect.STEP_SOUND, ParticleEffect.SNOW_SHOVEL);
                } else {
                    stack.setDurability((short) 0);
                }
                ChatUtilities.sendMessage(p, "Selected: " + spells.get(SpellSelected));
            }
        }
        if(e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR || e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
            Player p = e.getPlayer();
            ItemStack stack = p.getItemInHand();
            if(stack != null && stack.getType() == Material.BOW && stack.hasItemMeta() && stack.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(ChatColor.RED + "Bow")) {
                int SpellSelected = stack.getDurability();
                if(SpellSelected == 1) {
                    this.LightningShot.run();
                } else if (SpellSelected == 2) {
                    this.ExplosionShot.run();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my first spell: LightningShot

```
package me.Pixel;

import org.bukkit.entity.Arrow;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;

public class LightningShot extends BukkitRunnable {
    private Arrow arrow;
    private int tick = 1;

    public LightningShot(Arrow arrow) {
        this.arrow = arrow;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (arrow == null || arrow.isOnGround() || tick++ > 20 * 10) {
            this.cancel();
        } else {
            arrow.getWorld().strikeLightning(arrow.getLocation());
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my second spell: `ExplosionShot` (I'm trying to make an "explosion wave")

```
package me.Pixel;

import org.bukkit.Color;
import org.bukkit.FireworkEffect;
import org.bukkit.FireworkEffect.Type;
import org.bukkit.entity.Arrow;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;

public class ExplosionShot extends BukkitRunnable {
    private Arrow arrow;
    private int tick = 1;

    public ExplosionShot(Arrow arrow) {
        this.arrow = arrow;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (arrow == null || arrow.isOnGround() || tick++ > 20 * 10) {
            this.cancel();
        } else {
            arrow.getWorld().createExplosion(arrow.getLocation(), 1);
            FireworkEffect.builder().with(Type.BALL).withColor(Color.AQUA).withFade(Color.FUCHSIA).flicker(true).trail(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, somehow the `ExplosionShot` and `LightningShot` are combining so the LightningShot has explosions at the arrow's trail?

So if a user clicks their right mouse button there should be a message in chat that says:

> [X] (this is my chat utility so this is nothing to worry about) Selected: LightningShot

And if they click their right mouse button again:

> [X] Selected: ExplosionShot

And then it should create this "explosion wave" as it's following the arrow, but I can't get the scroller to work.

Comment: Your `onEntityShootBow` and `onEntityShootBow1` methods both listen to the same `EntityShootBowEvent`, that is why it is running both types of tasks. If I understand you correctly you want to cycle between the spells when right clicking. Think about what this task entails, what's involved here? You need to figure out when the player right clicks. You need to store what kind of spell the player has selected somewhere. Then, when the player right clicks, figure out what spell they have selected and run the appropriate task.

Comment: @AdrianSohn So, what do i change in the main file to fix this?

Comment: At this point it seems like I would be spoon-feeding you the code, which won't help you learn and isn't, as far as I know, what Stack Overflow is for. You seem to have everything you need to solve the problem: You know how  to register events and you have a list of spells, meaning you know some data structures. Stack Overflow should be ones [last resort](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) for solving *specific* problems.

Comment: What you are asking for isn't a fix to a bug but code for a feature which isn't overly complex, and completely doable with some java experience and access to the API documentation and Bukkit tutorials.

Comment: I have noticed that you have been inappropriately using stack snippets when there either isn't code or the code isn't runnable. Please see: [Stack Snippets and non-runnable code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295634/stack-snippets-and-non-runnable-code). In addition, correctly tag your question; Java is not JavaScript and your code isn't relevant to Eclipse.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest that instead of using a BukkitRunnable, you make a new abstract class (ArrowSpell?) and make LightningShot and ExplosiveShot extend that class. You can add abstract methods to ArrowSpell which LightningShot and ExplosiveShot must implement, such as onShoot(EntityShootBowEvent) or onHit(EntityDamageByEntityEvent) which it does not listen for, but get passed to it. I actually did something similar, you can see an example here:
https://github.com/ViperLordX/Divinity/tree/master/src/redempt/divinity/ability/modifier

This way, you don't need to use a BukkitRunnable, which is, from what I see, a very awkward way of doing it.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: How would one spawn an effect at the entity's location repeatedly without a repeating task? I see that your classes have an onTick() method, where would this be invoked from other than a 'BukkitRunnable'?

Comment: I invoke it, look at the Projectile class if ProjectileModifier is the one you're looking at, which I assume it is.