# Skeletons can use my plugin?

Tags: java, bukkit

Everything that changed is in here. Please help me lightning not spawning at the arrows location every tick

Main file

```
package me.Pixel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Arrow;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityShootBowEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
    public Main plugin;
    public List<String> spells = new ArrayList<String>();
    public getTargets getTargets = new getTargets();
    private Arrow arrow;
    public LightningShot LightningShot = new LightningShot(arrow);

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {    
        plugin = this;
        this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
        spells.add("LightningShot");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command,
            String label, String[] args) {
        if(label.equalsIgnoreCase("bow")) {
            if(!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You need to be an in-game player to execute this command!");
            }else{
                Player p = (Player)sender;
                if(sender.hasPermission("bow.bow")) { 
                ItemStack stack = new ItemStack(Material.BOW);
                ItemMeta stackMeta = stack.getItemMeta();
                stackMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.AQUA + "Magic" + ChatColor.RED + "Bow");
                stack.setItemMeta(stackMeta);
                p.getInventory().addItem(stack);
                ChatUtilities.sendMessage(p, "You now have the powerfull Magic Bow");
                }else{
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "No Permission!");
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @EventHandler
    public void onEntityShootBow(EntityShootBowEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getProjectile() instanceof Arrow) {
            Arrow a = (Arrow) ev.getProjectile();
            if (a.getShooter() instanceof Player) {
                ItemStack bow = ev.getBow();
                if (bow.hasItemMeta() && bow.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(ChatColor.AQUA + "Magic" + ChatColor.RED + "Bow")) {
                new LightningShot(a);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onClick(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
        if(e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR || e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
            Player p = e.getPlayer();
            ItemStack stack = p.getItemInHand();
            if(stack != null && stack.getType() == Material.BOW && stack.hasItemMeta() && stack.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(ChatColor.AQUA + "Magic" + ChatColor.RED + "Bow")) {
                int SpellSelected = stack.getDurability();
                if(SpellSelected == 1) {
                    this.LightningShot.run();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my LightningShot file

```
package me.Pixel;

import org.bukkit.entity.Arrow;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;

public class LightningShot extends BukkitRunnable {
    private Arrow arrow;
    private int tick = 1;

    public LightningShot(Arrow arrow) {
        this.arrow = arrow;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (arrow == null || arrow.isOnGround() || tick++ > 20 * 10) {
            this.cancel();
        } else {
            arrow.getWorld().strikeLightning(arrow.getLocation());
        }
    }
}
```

So I hope you can help me to get it working.
This is all the new code.

Comment: Have you read my comment on another one of your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36954963/spell-scroller-doesnt-work)s? Stop misusing Stack Snippets, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if the Bow, the Arrow was shoot from is a "Magic Bow", you can get the `ItemStack` of the Bow at the `EntityShootBowEvent`: `event.getBow()`. Now you can look if the Name of the Bow at the Event equals the Name of the Bow you gave the player at the "/bow" command.

Hope this helps you :) And sorry for my Bad English ;D

EDIT:
Like this

```
@EventHandler
public void onEntityShootBow(EntityShootBowEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getProjectile() instanceof Arrow) {
        Arrow a = (Arrow) ev.getProjectile();
        if (a.getShooter() instanceof Player) {
            ItemStack bow = ev.getBow();
            if (bow.hasItemMeta() && bow.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(ChatColor.AQUA + "Magic" + ChatColor.RED + "Bow")) {
                System.out.println("Launching LightningShot...");
                new LightningShot(arrow).runTaskTimer(this, 0, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT #2:

LightningShot.java:

```
package me.Pixel;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.entity.Arrow;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitTask;

public class LightningShot {
    private static int interval = 5;

    Arrow arrow;
    int tick = interval;

    public LightningShot(Arrow a) {
        arrow = a;

        BukkitTask[] task = new BukkitTask[1];
        task[0] = Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskTimerAsynchronously(Main.plugin, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (arrow == null || arrow.isOnGround() || arrow.isDead() || tick >= 200) {
                    System.out.println("Stopping...");
                    task[0].cancel();
                } else {
                    tick += interval;
                    System.out.println("Launching Lightning...");
                    Location loc = arrow.getLocation();
                    System.out.println("At " + loc.getWorld().getName() + " " + loc.getX() + "/"+ loc.getY() + "/" + loc.getZ());
                    loc.getWorld().strikeLightning(arrow.getLocation());
                }
            }
        }, interval, interval);
    }
}
```

EntityShootBowEvent:

```
@EventHandler
public void onEntityShootBow(EntityShootBowEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getProjectile() instanceof Arrow) {
        Arrow a = (Arrow) ev.getProjectile();
        if (a.getShooter() instanceof Player) {
            System.out.println("Launching LightningShot...");
            new LightningShot(a);
        }
    }
}
```

You can Change the interval to Change how often a Lightning is spawned.

EDIT #3:

Main.java

```
package me.Pixel;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Arrow;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityShootBowEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
    public static Main plugin;
    public Set<String> spells = new HashSet<String>();

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        plugin = this;
        this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
        spells.add("LightningShot");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("bow")) {
            if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You need to be an in-game player to execute this command!");
            } else {
                Player p = (Player) sender;
                if (sender.hasPermission("bow.bow")) {
                    ItemStack stack = new ItemStack(Material.BOW);
                    ItemMeta stackMeta = stack.getItemMeta();
                    stackMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.AQUA + "Magic" + ChatColor.RED + "Bow");
                    stack.setItemMeta(stackMeta);
                    p.getInventory().addItem(stack);
                    p.sendMessage("You now have the powerfull Magic Bow");
                } else {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "No Permission!");
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onEntityShootBow(EntityShootBowEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getProjectile() instanceof Arrow) {
            Arrow a = (Arrow) ev.getProjectile();
            if (a.getShooter() instanceof Player) {
                ItemStack bow = ev.getBow();
                if (bow.hasItemMeta() && bow.getItemMeta().getDisplayName()
                        .equals(ChatColor.AQUA + "Magic" + ChatColor.RED + "Bow")) {
                    new LightningShot(a);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LightningShot.java

```
package me.Pixel;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.entity.Arrow;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitTask;

public class LightningShot {

    Arrow arrow;
    int tick = 3;

    public LightningShot(Arrow a) {
        arrow = a;

        BukkitTask[] task = new BukkitTask[1];
        task[0] = Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskTimerAsynchronously(Main.plugin, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (arrow == null || arrow.isOnGround() || arrow.isDead() || tick >= 200) {
                    task[0].cancel();
                } else {
                    tick += 1;
                    Location loc = arrow.getLocation();
                    loc.getWorld().strikeLightning(arrow.getLocation());
                }
            }
        }, 3, 1);
    }
}
```

Both are the full classes I used and it worked...

Comment: Man you are a awesome person :P and your english is fine tho xD

Comment: No problem and thank you :) Can you please mark my answer as right than?!

Comment: I did it like this now.

    @EventHandler
    public void onEntityShootBow(EntityShootBowEvent event) {
        if(event.getProjectile() instanceof Arrow) {
         if (!(event.getBow() instanceof Plugin))
                return;
            Arrow arrow = (Arrow) event.getProjectile();
            new LightningShot(arrow).runTaskTimer(this, 0, 1);
        }
    }

Comment: Oh I didn't thought that a ItemStack could be instance of a Plugin...

Comment: Well it suggested it for me so...

Comment: Than use my solution ;D

Comment: It does not give the solution after the event i cant add the .getbow()

Comment: Let me post the main file as it is now

Comment: I now have added the Main file as it is now into the topic here take a look i did it like this now

Comment: I think you can copy this solution to `onEntityShootBow1` and only change the sort of shot ;)

Comment: Uhm it works now, but the lightning doesnt spawn xD

Comment: Please add a `System.out.println("Launch LightningShot...")` after `new LightningShot....` to see if it is launched

Comment: When i do that it gives an error on System that says delete this tocken

Comment: I've edited my answer... It isn't possible that you get an Error because of This...

Comment: yea it launched...

Comment: It says Launching LightningShot... in my command prompt

Comment: Then it is a problem in your LightningShot class

Comment: I will add the LightningShot class in my question

Comment: I added it, just take a look

Comment: I tried it on my Server and it works... I mean the code from my second EDIT

Comment: hmm... weird... i dont know how its not working

Comment: Have you tried my new Code? (EDIT #2)

Comment: Oh sry I forgot to include the Displayname-check again, but I think you Can do that on your own

Comment: In lightningshot i get the error: Cannot refer to a non-final variable task inside an inner class defined in a different method. And this error in my main file: Multiple markers at this line
 - The method run() is undefined for the type 
  LightningShot
 - The method run() is undefined for the type 
  LightningShot

Comment: As you can see in my EntityShootBowEvent, there is no Method for LightningShot. So only use 'new LightningShot(arrow);'. Nothing else. The problem with final is maybe because you don't use a Array for the BukkitTask as I did. You don't have to change anything in the LightningShot class, I posted. Just copy and paste

Comment: but that does not solve the problem with the non-final task and run() problem

Comment: Okay, let me refresh all my files on this topic, you can check for my mistakes okay? Because the lightning still aint spawning

Comment: What is the `PlayerInteractEvent` for?

Comment: Uhm... now that you say it xD

Comment: Deleted the `PlayerInteractEvent` still lightning doesnt spawn

Comment: I like you ;P It works now xD

Comment: You are welcome :) But please mark my answer as solution ;)

Comment: plugins works, 1 more question everytime i shoot and there are players nearby, my cmd gets spammed with the msg: <player> Received package. How to get rid of this xD

Comment: I never had this before... So sorry I really don't know. Maybe it is because I lightning is spawned so often